# Properties of exponents with Euler's number and logarithims

Tags: algebra-precalculus

How does $80e^{ln(5)t/(20)}$ equal $80(5)^{t/20}$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should know that $e^{\ln x}=x$. So, $e^{\ln5 \cdot \frac{t}{20}} = (e^{\ln5})^\frac{t}{20} =5^\frac{t}{20}  $

Answer (score 0):

Remember that $e^{\ln u}=u$ for $u>0$, so $e^{\ln(5)}=5$. Can you do the rest?